# Spark Structured Streaming Window() function - GeneratedIterator grows beyond 64 KB

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I am running the following Sliding Window SQL query using Spark Structured Streaming approach.

```
"SELECT  WINDOW(record_time, \"120 seconds\",\"1 seconds\"), COUNT(*) FROM records GROUP BY  WINDOW(record_time, \"120 seconds\",\"1 seconds\")";
```

I am getting the following error if I keep the window Size as 120 seconds and sliding interval as 1 seconds:

> org.codehaus.janino.JaninoRuntimeException: Code of method "agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator;)V" of class "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator" grows beyond 64 KB

For Window(90s,1s) and Window(120s,2s) its working fine.

Even though I got this error, but still I got the output for the query on the console.

Is this Ok? Should I ignore this error?

Comment: I have few more finding: the query above give the error if I run using it using readStream() from Kafka. A producer is putting data from a .csv file. But if I run the same query on the .csv file directly, then there is no such error, either using read() or readStream().

Answer (score 1):

Just try saying 'window' instead. So, your query should look as follows:

```
SELECT  window, COUNT(*) FROM records GROUP BY  WINDOW(record_time, "120 seconds","1 seconds");
```